# Find the difference between positive and negative peaks MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to find the difference between positive and negative peaks where the difference is greater than +-3.

I am using `findpeaks` function in MATLAB to find the positive and negative peaks of the data. 
In an example of my code:

```
[Ypos, Yposloc] =  findpeaks(YT0);
[Yneg, Ynegloc] =  findpeaks(YT0*-1);
Yneg = Yneg*-1;
```

`Yposloc` and `Ynegloc` return the locations of the positive and negative peaks in the data.

I want to concatenate `Ypos` and `Yneg` based on the order of the peaks.

For example, my peaks are

```
Ypos = [11 6 -10 -10 6 6 6 6 6 -5]
Yneg = [-12 -14 -11 -11 -11 5 5 5 -6]
```

Locations in `YT0`

```
Yposloc = [24 63 79 84 93 95 97 100 156]
Ynegloc = [11 51 78 81 85 94 96 99 154]
```

In this case, where both `Yposloc` and `Ynegloc` are 9x1, I can do the following;

```
nColumns = size(Yposs,2);
YTT0 = [Yneg, Ypos]';
YTT0 = reshape(YTT0(:),nColumns,[])';
YTT0 = diff(YTT0)
YT0Change = numel(YTT0(YTT0(:)>=3 | YTT0(:)<=-3));
```

Total changes that I am interested is `6`

However, I need to concatenate `Yneg` and `Ypos` automatically, based on their locations. So I think I need to to do an `if` statement to figure out if my positive or negative peaks come first? Then, I am not sure how to tackle the problem of when `Ypos` and `Yneg` are different sizes.

I am running this script multiple times where data changes and the negative/positive peak order are constantly changing. Is there a simple way I can compare the peak locations or am I on the right track here?

Comment: i am not quite sure what your goal is. you have minima and maxima and the corresponding location. Then you calcualte the gain or loss from those  and want to count where the difference between min and max (or max and min) is bigger 3. Am i right so far? Is that all the comaprison you want? How do you want to compare the location? wheter they are at the same point or have the same distance to each other or something else?

Comment: Hi Fin, I edited my post slightly. Yes you are right so far. Basically I am looking at movements in a face presentation to the camera. I am interested in 'noticeable' movements, i.e. when there is a big change from peak to peak. So far I want to compare the location based on what comes first, i.e. if the positive location comes first, compare to the negative, then to the positive and so fourth.

Answer (score 1):

I would check each minimum with *both the previous and the next maxima.* In order to do that you can first combine positive and negative peaks according to their order:

```
Y = zeros(1, max([Yposloc, Ynegloc]));
Yloc = zeros(size(Y));
Yloc(Yposloc) = Yposloc;
Yloc(Ynegloc) = Ynegloc;
Y(Yposloc) = Ypos; % I think you inserted one extra '6' in your code!
Y(Ynegloc) = Yneg;
Y = Y(Yloc ~= 0) % this is the combined signal
Yloc = Yloc(Yloc ~= 0) % this is the combined locations

% Y =
%
%   -12   11  -14    6  -11  -10  -11  -10  -11    6    5    6    5    6    5    6   -6   -5
%
% Yloc =
%
%    11   24   51   63   78   79   81   84   85   93   94   95   96   97   99  100  154  156
```

And then calculate the differences:

```
diff(Y)

% ans =
%
%    23  -25   20  -17    1   -1    1   -1   17   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1  -12    1
```

If you want changes of at least 6 units:

```
num = sum(abs(diff(Y)) > 6)

% num =
%
%     6
```

Comment: Hi erfan, thank you so much for this. Working through this now - Y = zeroes(1,max([yposloc, ynegloc])) returns 'error using zeroes, size inputs must be scalar. Not sure how to combat this? (sorry - bit of a newbie with matlab!)

Comment: Hi Josh. I think your `Yposloc` and `Ynegloc` are in a different orientation from your examples. What does `size(Yposloc)` return? Probably `max([Yposloc; Ynegloc])` (with semicolon) will solve the problem.

Comment: It returns  ans = 9     1.. I think i confused you by writing it out like 1x9, sorry!

Comment: in the posted data sample Ypos has 10 values while Yneg and both loc only have 9. that might be an issue

Comment: Yes, I manually corrected it to get the output. The issue here is with `max` returning multiple values. Simply replace the comma in `max([Yposloc, Ynegloc])` with semicolon

Answer (score 1):

```
Ypos = [11 6 -10 -10 6 6 6 6 -5];
Yneg = [-12 -14 -11 -11 -11 5 5 5 -6];
Yposloc = [24 63 79 84 93 95 97 100 156];
Ynegloc = [11 51 78 81 85 94 96 99 154];

TOTAL=[Yposloc Ynegloc;Ypos Yneg];
%creatin a vector with positions in row 1 and values in row 2
[~,position]=sort(TOTAL(1,:));

%resort this matrix so the values are in the orginial order
TOTAL_sorted=TOTAL(:,position);
%look at the changes of the values
changes=diff(TOTAL_sorted(2,:));

if changes(1)>0
    disp('First value was a Minimum')
else
    disp('First value was a MAximum')
end
%same structure at the TOTAL matrix
%abs(changes)>3 produces a logical vector that shows where the absolute values was bigger
%than 3, in my opinon its rather intresting where the end is then were the start is
% thats why i add +1
Important_changes=TOTAL_sorted(:,find(abs(changes)>3)+1);

plot(TOTAL_sorted(1,:),TOTAL_sorted(2,:))
hold on
plot(Important_changes(1,:),Important_changes(2,:),...
    'Marker','o','MarkerSize',10, 'LineStyle','none');
hold off
```